# Broken lambda in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I was trying something with lambdas, to better understand how they work when I ran into this behavior. I guess I will let the code speak for itself

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'
>>> a = 5; b = 7
>>> func1 = lambda True: a if True else b
>>> func1(True)
5
>>> func1(False)    # <== why?
7
>>> func2 = lambda x: a if True else b
>>> func2(True)
5
>>> func2(False)
5
```

I ran 'dis' on the functions and this is what came out:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(func1)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(func2)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (a)
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>   10 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (b)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

The only difference is between the [LOAD_FAST](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST) and the [LOAD_GLOBAL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL)

Why is it that the 'False' in func1 gets evaluated at all?

On a side note, 3.3 doesn't allow this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> a = 5; b = 7
>>> func = lambda True: a if True else b
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    func = lambda True: a if True else b
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`True` and `False` are [keywords](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python 3, you can't use them as a variables anymore . And in Python 2 they are just simple variables and you can override their value by a simple assignment.

Python 2:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> def f(True):
...     print True
...     
>>> f(1)     #assigns 1 to local variable True
1
>>> f(False) #assigns False to local variable True
False
```

Python 3:

```
>>> True = False
  File "<ipython-input-2-7cebd69d5d15>", line 1
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
```

Comment: I liked both answers, but [@ashwch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/846892/ashwini-chaudhary) called them by their names. How wrong I was to think 'True' and 'False' were immutable objects! I wonder when Python 3 will reign over 2...

Answer (score 4):

```
func1 = lambda True: a if True else b
```

Here, you named your lambda's argument `True`. That means the `True` in the body refers to the argument, whatever that happens to be. It's roughly equivalent to

```
def func1(x):
    return a if x else b
```

On the other hand,

```
func2 = lambda x: a if True else b
```

here, the argument has a more reasonable name, so `True` refers to the built-in variable. It's roughly equivalent to

```
def func2(x):
    return a if True else b
```

In Python 3, you can no longer name variables `True`.